# Reactives: invalid (NULL) left side of assignment

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to extract an output of a personal function called tests.stats()

I make a function with `return` statement:

```
   return(c(list.test.1, list.test.2 ,list.test.3, list.test.4))
```

Where each `list.test.<i>` is a `list` object.

In Shiny Server:

```
 outlist() <- reactive({
   if(is.null(input$datafile)){
     return()
   }
   if(is.null(input$varinteret)
      &&is.null(input$vartemps)
      &&is.null(input$varsujet)
      &&is.null(input$varprod) 
      &&is.null(input$apparie)
      &&is.null(input$tempsrefouinon)
      &&is.null(input$prodrefouinon)
      &&is.null(input$checkprod)
      &&is.null(input$checkprodref)){
     return()
   } else {
     data<-filedata()
     res <- tests.stats(data = data(),
              y = input$varinteret, 
              group = input$varprod, 
              group2 = input$vartemps, 
              sujet = input$varsujet, 
              apparie = input$apparie, 
              temoin = input$prodrefouinon, 
              TemoinName = input$checkprodref)
   }
```

and the error message:

```
Warning: Error in <-: invalid (NULL) left side of assignment
Stack trace (innermost first):
    40: server [C:\Users\itm\Desktop\Documents\appli/server.R#357]
     1: shiny::runApp
Error in outlist() <- reactive({ : invalid (NULL) left side of assignment
```

Why am I receiving this error?

Comment: replace `outlist()` with `outlist`

Answer (score 15):

This happened because of this assignment:

```
outlist() <- reactive({...})
```

This is incorrect syntax as you are telling Shiny that `outlist` is an already defined reactive expression and that you should evaluate it. You are then trying to assign something to this reactive expression in a syntax that Shiny does not understand.

Therefore if you instead use:

```
outlist <- reactive({...})
```

You have now correctly defined the `outlist` as a reactive Shiny object which can be called with `outlist()` elsewhere in the code.

The documentation for this topic is very good, and can be found here:

http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/reactive.html

http://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/lesson6/

It seems like you could also make use of `validate` and `need` to handle your sea of requires inputs:

http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/validation.html

And also a style guide for your code from Lord Hadley:

http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Style.html