# object of type 'closure' is not subsettable in shiny. Working on a simple RGL plotting function

Tags: r, shiny, rgl

I was coding in shiny with the `rgl` and `shinyRGL` package, trying to plot a 3D line plot by having the users insert a `csv` file of a specific format. But the object type closure error keeps showing up. It seems like because it can't find the function `plot3d`, or I may be wrong.

Here's the code:

**UI**

```
library(shiny)
library(rgl)
library(shinyRGL)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("title panel"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      helpText("Please select a CSV file with the correct format."),
      tags$hr(),
      fileInput("file","Choose file to upload",accept = c(
        'text/csv',
        'text/comma-separated-values',
        'text/tab-separated-values',
        'text/plain',
        '.csv',
        '.tsv',
        label = h3("File input"))
    ),
    tags$hr(),
    checkboxInput('header', 'Header', TRUE),

    actionButton("graph","PLOT!")
    ),


mainPanel(textOutput("text1"),
          webGLOutput("Aplot")))
)
)
```

**Server**

```
library(shiny)
library(rgl)
library(shinyRGL)

options(shiny.maxRequestSize = 9*1024^2)
shinyServer(
  function(input, output) {


    output$text1 <- renderText({
    paste("You have selected", input$select)
  })
    output$"Aplot" <- renderWebGL({
      inFile <- reactive(input$file)
      theFrames <- eventReactive(input$graph,read.csv(inFile$datapath,
header = input$header))
plot3d(theFrames[[4]],theFrames[[5]],theFrames[[6]],xlab="x",ylab="y",zlab 
= "z", type = "l", col = ifelse(theFrames[[20]]>0.76,"red","blue"))
   })
})
```

**Error**

> Warning: 
>       package hinyRGL?was built under R version 3.3.1 
>       Warning: Error in [[: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
>           Stack trace (innermost first):
>               70: plot3d
>               69: func [C:\Users\Ian\workspace\Copy of Leap
>           SDK/Test\App_1/server.R#19]
>               68: output$Aplot
>                1: runApp

Comment: It's not that it can't find the function, it's that somewhere in those functions you're trying to subset a closure (a function), which obviously doesn't work. Try swapping out subsetted dynamic terms with static placeholders (anything that you know will let the function run) so you can figure out which term is causing the issue.

Comment: @alistaire It seems like the issue is within my XYZ parameter "theFrames[[...]]". But I don't know what's causing it or how to fix it.

Comment: What's `str(theFrames)`?

Comment: @alistaire It is just the data frame which stores the csv file. The plot3d function access it for the XYZ coordinates for the plot.

Comment: I suspect `eventReactive` is somehow not returning what you expect.

Comment: @alistaire If i get rid of the eventReactive then my button for plotting wouldn't work.

Comment: Note that `shinyRGL` is not currently being maintained.  You will likely have better luck using `rglwidget` from CRAN, or (if you like to live on the bleeding edge) just `rgl` from R-forge or github.

Comment: @alistaire is there ever a case where the Shiny app runs fine on a localhost, but is throwing this error when deployed to an external Shiny server? That's what is currently happening right now- I'm seeing the error message on the browser screen with no stack trace or line, so it's difficult to begin knowing where to debug?

Comment: @YuChen Ugh, that situation is hard to debug. It's possible you can see more of what the problem is through your browser's console, though I haven't tried. You could try clearing your local environment out to see if it's because of some variable/function you have locally that you haven't built into the code, but that's a guess.

Answer (score 5):

Remember this error message, since it's very typical for shiny applications.

It almost always means, that you had a reactive value, but didn't use it with parentheses.

Concerning your code, I spotted this mistake here:

```
inFile <- reactive(input$file)
theFrames <- eventReactive(input$graph,read.csv(inFile$datapath,
    header = input$header)) 

plot3d(theFrames[[4]],theFrames[[5]],theFrames[[6]],xlab="x",ylab="y",zlab 
    = "z", type = "l", col = ifelse(theFrames[[20]]>0.76,"red","blue"))
```

You use `inFile` like a normal variable, but it isn't. It's a reactive value and thus has to be called with `inFile()`. The same goes for `theFrames`, which you called with `theFrames[[i]]`, but should be called with `theFrames()[[i]]`.

So the correct version would be

```
inFile <- reactive(input$file)
theFrames <- eventReactive(input$graph,read.csv(inFile()$datapath,
    header = input$header)) 

plot3d(theFrames()[[4]],theFrames()[[5]],theFrames()[[6]],xlab="x",ylab="y",zlab 
    = "z", type = "l", col = ifelse(theFrames()[[20]]>0.76,"red","blue"))
```

Maybe some additional info about the error message: Shiny evaluates the variables only when they are needed, so the reactive `theFrames`, containing the error, is executed from inside the `plot3d` function. That is why the error message tells you something about the error being in `plot3d`, even if the error lies somewhere else.

Comment: I fixed the 'closure' error following what you said, thanks a lot. But now it's giving me another error massage saying: ' Warning: Error in <-: invalid (NULL) left side of assignment
Stack trace (innermost first):
    69: func [C:\Users\Ian\workspace\Copy of Leap SDK Test\App_1/server.R#15]
    68: output$Aplot
     1: runApp '

Comment: @IANLee Then you probably put too many `()`s inside your code. See the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35769388/reactives-invalid-null-left-side-of-assignment).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you should look at your naming conventions. I have always seen this error when I am using variable name same as names of any function defined in packages or any function defined by me.

For example:

```
header = input$header
inFile = input$file
```

You should **always restrict** yourself in using these kinds of names, it will always be useful.

Thanks :)