# Shiny reactive XY Plot: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Tags: r, shiny, closures, reactive

being a shiny newcomer myself, I struggle with adapting an [example code](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-examples/tree/master/063-superzip-example) to my particular dataset. My dataset is a "development subset" of the [yelp dataset challenge](https://www.yelp.com/dataset).

**My goal** is to create a scatter plot of "stars" vs "number of reviews" of the restaurants in the current map section.

**What I got:** a map that shows markers for restaurants as well as a working filter to count the visible restaurants as debug message in the console.

**My problem:**

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:4587
num restaurants: 194 ## <- this number changes when changing the map section##
Warning: Error in [: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
Stack trace (innermost first):
107: FUN
106: lapply
105: concat
104: lrep
103: latticeParseFormula
102: xyplot.formula
101: xyplot
100: print
 99: renderPlot [C:/SomePath/server.R#54]
 89: <reactive:plotObj>
 78: plotObj
 77: origRenderFunc
 76: output$scatterStarsReviewCount
  1: runApp
```

I read a lot of stack overflow posts which are dealing with that error message, but it seems that they all boil down to solutions similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38368064/5922528) or [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24240693/5922528). Unfortunately and to all I know so far, these hints are not helping to solve my problem. 
I don't understand why the abovementioned example code is working and mine throws this error. They look very very similar.

**Current Code:**

**ui.r**

```
    library(shiny)
    library(leaflet)


    navbarPage(
      "Yelp",
      id = "nav",

      tabPanel(
        "Interactive map",
        div(
          class = "outer",

          tags$head(# Include our custom CSS
            includeCSS("styles.css"),
            includeScript("gomap.js")),

          # If not using custom CSS, set height of leafletOutput to a number instead of percent
          leafletOutput("map", width = "100%", height = "100%"),

          # Shiny versions prior to 0.11 should use class = "modal" instead.
          absolutePanel(
            id = "controls",
            class = "panel panel-default",
            fixed = TRUE,
            draggable = FALSE,
            top = 60,
            left = "auto",
            right = 20,
            bottom = "auto",
            width = 330,
            height = "auto",

            h3('ScatterPlot'),

            plotOutput("scatterStarsReviewCount", height = 250)
          )
        )
      )
    )
```

**server.r**

```
    library(leaflet)
    library(RColorBrewer)
    library(scales)
    library(lattice)
    library(dplyr)

    # Read pre-processed data
    bizrates <- read.table("bizrates.dat")

    function(input, output, session) {
      ## Interactive Map ###########################################

      # Create the map
      output$map <- renderLeaflet({

        Sbizrates = bizrates

        # generate map
        leaflet() %>%
          addTiles() %>%
          addTiles(urlTemplate = "http://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png")  %>%
          mapOptions(zoomToLimits = "always") %>%

          addMarkers(
            lat = Sbizrates$biz_dat.latitude,
            lng = Sbizrates$biz_dat.longitude,
            clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions(),
            popup = Sbizrates$biz_dat.name
          )
      })


      # A reactive expression that returns the set of restaurants that are
      # in bounds right now
      restaurantsInBounds <- reactive({
        if (is.null(input$map_bounds))
          return(bizrates[FALSE,])
        bounds <- input$map_bounds
        latRng <- range(bounds$north, bounds$south)
        lngRng <- range(bounds$east, bounds$west)

        subset(bizrates,
               biz_dat.latitude >= latRng[1] & biz_dat.latitude <= latRng[2] &
                 biz_dat.longitude >= lngRng[1] & biz_dat.longitude <= lngRng[2])
      })

      output$scatterStarsReviewCount <- renderPlot({
        # If no restaurants are in view, don't plot
        if (nrow(restaurantsInBounds()) == 0)
         return(NULL)

        cat(file=stderr(), "num restaurants:", nrow(restaurantsInBounds()),"\n")

        print(xyplot(stars ~ reviewCount, data = restaurantsInBounds()), 
                     xlim = range(bizrates$biz_dat.stars), 
                     ylim = range(bizrates$biz_dat.review_count)
              )
      })
    }
```

**Sample Data Set: bizrates.dat**

```
"biz_dat.business_id" "biz_dat.name" "biz_dat.stars" "biz_dat.longitude" "biz_dat.latitude" "biz_dat.state" "biz_dat.attributes..Take.out." "biz_dat.attributes..Takes.Reservations." "biz_dat.attributes..Wi.Fi." "biz_dat.attributes.Caters" "biz_dat.review_count"
"5" "mVHrayjG3uZ_RLHkLj-AMg" "Emil's Lounge" 4.5 -79.8663507 40.408735 "PA" TRUE FALSE "no" TRUE 11
"6" "KayYbHCt-RkbGcPdGOThNg" "Alexion's Bar & Grill" 4 -80.067534 40.415517 "PA" TRUE FALSE "free" FALSE 15
"13" "b9WZJp5L1RZr4F1nxclOoQ" "Gab & Eat" 4.5 -80.0847998 40.3967441 "PA" TRUE FALSE "no" TRUE 38
"19" "rv7CY8G_XibTx82YhuqQRw" "Long John Silver's" 3.5 -80.0937037 40.3868915 "PA" TRUE FALSE "no" FALSE 3
"22" "wqu7ILomIOPSduRwoWp4AQ" "Denny's" 4 -80.073426 40.391255 "PA" TRUE FALSE "no" FALSE 7
"24" "P1fJb2WQ1mXoiudj8UE44w" "Papa J's" 3.5 -80.0854582 40.4082572 "PA" TRUE TRUE "no" TRUE 46
"26" "PK6aSizckHFWk8i0oxt5DA" "McDonald's" 2 -79.910032 40.412086 "PA" TRUE FALSE "free" FALSE 5
"30" "6ilJq_05xRgek_8qUp36-g" "Steak 'n Shake" 2 -79.9044562 40.413496 "PA" TRUE FALSE "no" FALSE 36
"32" "MKyk4F4HSzHF8v-4cYe3Ww" "Sing Sing" 3.5 -79.9151108 40.4094884 "PA" FALSE TRUE "no" FALSE 25
"37" "McikHxxEqZ2X0joaRNKlaw" "Rock Bottom" 3.5 -79.9151108 40.4094884 "PA" TRUE TRUE "no" FALSE 94
```

**Note:** In case someone wants to execute the code, the missing files (styles.css, gomap.js) can be found [here](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-examples/tree/master/063-superzip-example).

Any help and ideas is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check where it went wrong, I made some `print()`statements in your code for making the xy-plot, for example `print(colnames(restaurantsInBounds()))`. It turns out that the colnames are

```
[1] "biz_dat.latitude" "biz_dat.longitude" "biz_dat.name" "biz_dat.stars" "biz_dat.review_count"
```

But in the plotting function you refer to other columns:

```
print(xyplot(stars ~ reviewCount, data = restaurantsInBounds()),
```

You can fix it by modifying your function accordingly:

```
 output$scatterStarsReviewCount <- renderPlot({
    # If no restaurants are in view, don't plot
    if (nrow(restaurantsInBounds()) == 0)
      return(NULL)

    cat(file=stderr(), "num restaurants:", nrow(restaurantsInBounds()),"\n")

    print(colnames(restaurantsInBounds()))
    print(xyplot(biz_dat.stars ~ biz_dat.review_count, data = restaurantsInBounds()), 
          xlim = range(bizrates$biz_dat.stars), 
          ylim = range(bizrates$biz_dat.review_count)
    )
  })
```

result:

[image]

Hope this helps!